# Closed form Laurent Series for $\sin(z+1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the Laurent Series of $\sin(z+\frac 1z)$ in a "closed form", i.e. a formula for each coefficient.

What I tried is the following:

$\begin{aligned}
\sin(z+\frac 1z)&=\sin z\cos z^{-1}+\sin z^{-1}\cos z\\
&=\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\Big)\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{-2n}}{(2n)!}\Big)+\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{-2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}\Big)\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}\Big)
\end{aligned}$

I can expand out the terms to get the "Cauchy product", however I have no formula for the general coefficient.

Is there a better way?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: _One_ other way (I don't know whether it's better) is to insert $z + \frac1z$ into the power series of $\sin$, so that you get $$\sin(1+\frac{1}{z}) = (z+\frac1z)-\frac{(z+1/z)^3}{6} + \frac{(z + 1/z)^5}{120} - \cdots$$ and use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arthur states, one idea is to expand the sine into a Taylor series and get

$$\sin{\left ( z+\frac1z \right )} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)!} \left ( z+\frac1z \right )^{2 k+1}$$

Now, the residue involves finding the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the above expansion.  This means finding the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the general term $\left ( z+\frac1z \right )^{2 k+1}$.  This may be done by recognizing that this is the $(k+1)$th term in the expansion (try it out), so the coefficient is $\binom{2 k+1}{k+1}$.  Thus, the residue is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)!} \binom{2 k+1}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)!} = J_1(2)$$

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. May I ask what is $J_1(2)$?

Comment: @yoyostein: Bessel function of first kind of first order, evaluated at $z=2$.